# Symfony twig does not refresh my pages

Tags: php, html, apache, symfony, twig

Currently working on a symfony project 2.8 on Windows 10.
I want to make inheritance with Twig 2.9.0 as explained in the good practices with symfony: http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/inheritance.html

I want my DOCTYPE html to be located in : `src/myProject/CoreBundle/Resources/views/layout.html.twig`

```
# {CoreBundle/Resources/views/layout.html.twig}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome !{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="{{ asset('assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Then my body block will be overriden in MyOwnBundle: `src/myProject/MyOwnBundle/Resources/views/layout.html.twig`

```
# {MyOwnBundle/Resources/views/layout.html.twig}

{% extends 'CoreBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <h1>Welcome to my Veterinary lab</h1>
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

{% endblock %}
```

Finally, my content block will be overriden in `src/myProject/MyOwnBundle/Resources/views/MyApp/index.html.twig`.

Here is my problem: I can access my homepage through my vhost at http://veto.local/ but when I modify anything in my layouts (for example the title block from "Welcome !" to "My Super Project") nothing happen while reloading the web page.

I truly think that its coming from the cache files but I did `php app/console cache:clear` three times, the process finishes as a clear statement but still, nothing is refreshed !

May you help me to know where does that comes from ?

To configure my vhost I followed the apache documentation: `httpd//:apache.developpez.com/cours/virtual-host/`

Here is my vhost.conf and I included this file at the end of my httpd.conf (`Include "C:\veterinary\veto_vhost.conf"`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName veto.local
    DocumentRoot C:\veterinary\veterinary\web

    DirectoryIndex app.php
    ErrorLog C:\veterinary\veterinary\veto-error.log
    CustomLog C:\veterinary\veterinary\veto-access.log combined
    <Directory "C:\veterinary\veterinary\web">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All

        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews

        AllowOverride all
        Require local
        Require all granted

    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thank you,

Best regards,

Comment: to be sure this is really a twig caching issue you can go into the folder `/var/cache/ENV/twig` (replacing `ENV` with the environment you are using) and delete all files there. The `cache:clear` command should do the same. If you can, I'd I'd recommend you develop locally (by running `php bin/console server:run` in your project root, This will enable the dev mode, start the php build in server correctly, and will take care of correct caches once you change files of your project)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're using production environment (`app.php` entrypoint) while developing you app..

Try http://veto.local/app_dev.php to use development environment, or if you really want to use production env use

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

because by default this command clear dev cache.

Answer (score 2):

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

clears the cache for the `dev` environment. You can reach that by calling `http://veto.local/app_dev.php`.
In this environment, changes to any files are automatically detected and there is no real need for clearing the cache. As the name suggests, this is the preferred environment during development.

`http://veto.local/` however is known as the `prod` environment.
Here changes to files are not automatically detected and you have to clear the cache manually to see the effects. You can do this by calling

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```